# Simplify the expression?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I was wondering if this could be written with only one summation symbol or simplified any other way?

$$=x_0q_0r_0\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty y_\ell z_\ell p_\ell + x_0 y_0 z_0 \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty q_\ell p_\ell r_\ell$$

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What would constitute a "simpler" expression?

Comment: Possibly with only one summation ?!! I am not sure if it can be done. I have many of such terms and trying to make the entire expression look more elegant.

Comment: The following is technically a single sum, but I don't know that I'd call it "simpler" or "more elegant": $$x_0 \,\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \,p_\ell\,(\,q_0 \,r_0 \,y_\ell \,z_\ell  \,+ \,y_0 \,z_0 \,q_\ell \,r_\ell\,)$$